# How to delete (and respawn) an item (coin) in java. (Using Controller class for spawning)

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list, items

I am a beginner programmer using Java. I am making my first simple game. I need coins (LinkedList items in my Controller class) to be removed after they have been picked up, and even better it would be when they could be spawned again in an another spot (I am using this:

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    for (int idx = 1; idx <= 1; ++idx){
          int r1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(590);
          this.r1=r1;
    }
    for (int idx = 1; idx <= 1; ++idx){
          int r2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(380);
          this.r2=r2;
```

to set my "coin" a random x and y variable).
I have already done everything right when it comes to spawning them in that random spot, and I also have made a Collision() method inside of my Player class. It looks like that:

```
private void Collision(){

    for(int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++){
        if(getBounds().intersects(c.get(i).getBounds())){
            Game.points++;
        }
    }

}
```

The points work fine (kind of) but I just can figure out what to do to remove the coin after it has been "picked up". I of course have an add and removeItem method inside of my Controller class:

```
    public void removeItem(Coin coin){
    c.remove(coin);
}
    public void addItem(Coin coin){
    c.add(coin);
}
```

The addItem is called in the Constructor of the Controller... 
I know it's a bit long but I wanted to make everything clear. I would be really happy if someone helped me because without that help the game is pointless. 
Thanks to everybody who helps me and if you need some further information just say.

EDIT:
This is my code:

```
private void Collision(){ 
  int newCount = 0; 
  while(iter.hasNext()){ 
    iter.next(); 
      for(int i=0; i<cb.size(); i++){ 
        if(getBounds().intersects(cb.get(i).getBounds())){ 
         Game.points++; 
         newCount++; 
         iter.remove();
      }
    } 
  } 
  for(int i = 0; i < newCount; i++){ 
    controller.addItem(new Coin());     
    newCount--; 
  }
}
```

I have an iterator declared in the controller:

```
static Iterator<Coin> iter = c.iterator();
```

and a getter function so i can use it in my player class:

```
public static Iterator<Coin> getCoinIterator(){ 
return iter; 
}
```

And down here it gets the iterator from controller to player class

```
private Iterator<Coin> iter = Controller.getCoinIterator();
```

I have even created next() and hasNext() methods in the controller but i still get a bunch of errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would not suggest you to add the same coin object again in another spot, but rather removing it and then adding a new one. I'm not sure if you already did this, because your code isn't here completely.

Edit:
In the Coins Constructor you would have to set its position randomly, so that`Coin coin = new Coin` creates a coin which already has its position set.
Alternatively you could call the position randomizer Method of your Controller on each coin.
To get this to work, you will have to add

```
private int x, y;
```

To your Coin class and set those to random values in the constructor. That way you do not need to randomize it anywhere else. Just create a Coin Object with new Coin and it has its Position.
Edit end

When it comes to removing the Coins, I would use an iterator loop like that (assuming c is your List)

```
int newCount = 0;
while(iter.hasNext()){
    Coin coin = iter.next();
    if(getBounds().intersects(coin.getBounds())){
        Game.Points++;
        newCount++
        iter.remove();
    }
}
for(int i = 0; i < newCount; i++){
    c.add(new Coin());
}
```

This kind of loop has the advantage, that you can remove the objects in the list without any risk and is rather easy to understand. I'm using newCount here to count how many coins have been removed and have to be added again. For this to work the constructor of Coin has to set its position randomly.

Edit:
An Iterator is used to get all elements of any Collection or List in order. When calling next() on it, it goes to the next Object in the List and returns it. hasNext() returns if the Iterator has Elements left, or if it has reached its end. And remove() deletes the current element, which is the last one returned by next().

In an Iterator Loop you check if there are Elements left, and as long as that is true you get the next element, check if it collides the player, and if it does do something.
This Something in our case is deleting that coin instance and creating a new one.
Edit end

Another thing I want to point out, is that LinkedLists are not very good for that purpose, I'd rather use ArrayLists, since they are faster and have random Acces, what means, that the time of any get or add call does not depend on the index. But in your small game that is not that big of a deal.

I hope this helps you.
If I made some mistakes in interpreting your code, please correct me.

Please excuse the typos, I typed the edit on my phone

Comment: You have to write that Loop in the method which checks for collisions, so in your case in the player

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your reply.  c is the variable for linked list <coin> in player class to get coin bounds. I don't really know the iterator loops yet ... but I guess that should work. My question is : in the if statement shouldn't it add 1 to newCount in order for the for loop to work? 3. The coin gets random position but in the controller constructor not in the coin constructor. Should I change it? Let me know. I still don't understand many things :D

Comment: Ok, I'll try to clarify some things in my answer

Comment: Great. That was very helpful. I'll now have to randomise the x and y of the coin in the coin constructor function and write the iterator loop in the player class. :) I'm also typing on my phone right now :D + you still forgot to add newCount++; not a problem I'll manage that :D

Comment: Hi. I still have got some problems. I changed everything in this your iterator loop that needed to be changed to equal the variables and so on, and it looks like this:    private void Collision(){
  
  int newCount = 0;
  while(iter.hasNext()){
      Coin coin = iter.next();
      for(int i=0; i<cb.size(); i++){
       if(getBounds().intersects(cb.get(i).getBounds())){
        Game.points++;
        newCount++;
        iter.remove();
       }
      }
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < newCount; i++){
      controller.addItem(new Coin());
      newCount--;
  }
 }    And I still get erors

Comment: What am i doing wrong? I have an iterator declared in the controller:    static Iterator<Coin> iter = c.iterator()    and a getter function so i can use it in my player class:    public static Iterator<Coin> getCoinIterator(){
  return iter;
 }    private Iterator<Coin> iter = Controller.getCoinIterator();     I have even created next() and hasNext() methods in the controller but i still get a bunch of errors. What should I do? Can anyone help? @AlexanderDaum maybe you can do something?

Comment: Could you please upload your whole code anywhere, so that I can take a look at it. It is just too difficult to help you with that little code

Comment: One mistake I can see, is that you only create your Iterator once. Every next () call will increment its internal counter, and when you are finished with your loop there are no more elements. And because you do not reinitialise it, hasNext will always return false. To fix this, create a new Iterator in getCoinIterator method and only use that. You should also delete your static Iterator, to not accidently use it. And take a look on your Iterator loop, I believe you made a mistake there too. You are not even using the Coin returned by next (). Look at my example, there is no inner for loop.